# Post JSON with PHP CURL to a Tin Can API LRS

Tags: php, json, post, curl

Sorry, I can only post 2 hyperlinks so I'm going to have to remove the http : //

**Background**
I'm, trying to convert the code  here: https://github.com/RusticiSoftware/TinCan_Prototypes/blob/92969623efebe2588fdbf723dd9f33165694970c/ClientPrototypes/StatementIssuer/StatementIssuer.java

into PHP, specifically the makeRequest function. This code posts data to a Tin Can Compliant Learner Record Store.

The current version of my PHP code is here:
tincanapi.co.uk/wiki/tincanapi.co.uk:MediaWikiTinCan

The specification for the Tin Can API which everything should conform to is here: 
scorm.com/wp-content/assets/tincandocs/TinCanAPI.pdf

There is also a working java script function that Posts data in the right format here (see the XHR_request function I think):
https://github.com/RusticiSoftware/TinCan_Prototypes/blob/92969623efebe2588fdbf723dd9f33165694970c/ClientPrototypes/GolfExample_TCAPI/scripts/TCDriver.js

I don't have access to the code or server that I'm posting to, but the end result should be an output here: beta.projecttincan.com/ClientPrototypes/ReportSample/index.html

**Problem**
I'm trying to use Curl to POST the data as JSON in PHP. Curl is returning 'false' but no error and is not posting the data.

On the recommendation of other questions on this site, I've tried adding 'json=' to the start of the POSTFIELDS, but since the Java and JavaScript versions does have this, I'm not sure this is right.

Can anybody suggest either how I might fix this or how I might get useful errors out of curl? My backup is to output the relevant JavaScript to the user's browser, but surely PHP should be able to do this server side?

Very grateful for any help.

Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least one thing is wrong: you should not be using `rawurlencode` on your `Authorization` header value.

Consider using php streams and `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` instead. The following code works.

```
function fopen_request_json($data, $url)
{
    $streamopt = array(
        'ssl' => array(
            'verify-peer' => false,
        ),
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'ignore_errors' => true,
            'header' =>  array(
                'Authorization: Basic VGVzdFVzZXI6cGFzc3dvcmQ=',
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'Accept: application/json, */*; q=0.01',
            ),
            'content' => json_encode($data),
        ),
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($streamopt);
    $stream = fopen($url, 'rb', false, $context);
    $ret = stream_get_contents($stream);
    $meta = stream_get_meta_data($stream);
    if ($ret) {
        $ret = json_decode($ret);
    }
    return array($ret, $meta);
}

function make_request()
{
    $url = 'https://cloud.scorm.com/ScormEngineInterface/TCAPI/public/statements';

    $statements = array(
        array(
            'actor' => array(
                'name' => array('Example Name'),
                'mbox'  => array('mailto:example@example.com'),
                'objectType' => 'Person',
            ),
            'verb' => 'experienced',
            'object' => array(
                'objectType' => 'Activity',
                'id'=> 'http://www.thincanapi.co.uk/wiki/index.php?Main_Page',
                'definition' => array(
                    'name' => array('en-US'=>'TinCanAPI.co.uk-tincanapi.co.uk'),
                    'description' => array('en-US'=> 'TinCanAPI.co.uk-tincanapi.co.uk'),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );
    return fopen_request_json($statements, $url);

}

list($resp, $meta) =  make_request();

var_export($resp); // Returned headers, including errors, are in $meta
```

Comment: Wow, thank you - you've gone well beyond what I asked or expected here. By the looks of things, you've written exactly what I need, from scratch. Am I ok to use your code as-is (with attribution)?

Comment: Yes you may, although from the look of your class I doubt you will be able to drop it in unaltered. This was much easier than reading, testing, and debugging your code. Curl is...painful.

Comment: Some minor tweaks, but not much. Here's your code working in my class file: http://www.tincanapi.co.uk/wiki/tincanapi.co.uk:MediaWikiTinCan#Code

Answer (score 2):

We've now released an open source library specifically for PHP, it uses a similar method as the accepted answer but rounds out the rest of the library as well. See:

http://rusticisoftware.github.io/TinCanPHP/

https://github.com/RusticiSoftware/TinCanPHP